# Maximum number of columns allowed in a table of Oracle 10g Express Edition?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I am getting an error if I exceed more than 31 columns in a table. The error is returned as follows:

`<div class="fielddata">First 31 columns displayed.</div>`

Though I'm able to insert data into all the columns, it is only displaying the first 31 columns.
I don't know how to get all columns. Can anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the horizontal scrollbar

Comment: What tool are you using to run the query?

Answer (score 0):

Per the **Oracle 10g Release 2 documentation**,

[Logical Database Limits](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/limits003.htm#i288032)

```
Columns     Per table                       1000 columns maximum
            Per index (or clustered index)  32 columns maximum
            Per bitmapped index             30 columns maximum
```